# Problems connecting to eduroam wifi - ubuntu touch

Tags: wireless, networking, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I am trying to connect to our university's eduroam wi-fi network with my Nexus 4 running Ubuntu touch (utopic latest build), but can't get past the first stage.  I wonder if anyone can help please?

I am following these instructions (which worked for my iPhone): http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/itsupport/mobile/eduroam/  But when I go to the bandit.st-andrews.ac.uk/connect page then follow the link to 'eduroam setup' I get the error message:

> Authorization Required
>   This server could not verify that you are authorised to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
>   Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at bandit.st-andrews.ac.uk Port 443

(Clearly it's the latter option (browser) as I haven't been asked for my credentials yet.) Is there a way round this, or am I just not going to be able to connect until further down the Ubuntu touch development road...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use Aquaris E4.5 (Ubuntu edition). For me the following settings for the network manager on the phone worked:

Wireless Security : WPA & WPA2 Enterprise

Authentification  : PEAP

Anonymous Id      : (none)

Certificate       : (none)

PEAP Version      : Version 0

Auth. protocol    : MSCHAPv2

user name         : your_login

password          : your_password

hope this helps,
Julien

Comment: St Andrews requires us to install a certificate on whatever device we use, so my problem is in getting a certificate onto my phone... Do you think if I asked them for the one that would be used for an Ubuntu computer it might be possible to manually install that on my phone? (Or are the two systems still too different for that?)

Btw, I'm now on an E4.5, hoping to get the M10 next month (which will no doubt face the same hurdles!)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some variation between the eduroam setups at different organisations: my configuration works at QUT (Bris Vegas, AU), and worked at ANU, but doesn't get to the IP address stage at Monash Clayton campus (Melbourne, AU). 
My configuration - almost the same as [Julien's](https://askubuntu.com/users/489400/julien), above;

Wireless Security : WPA & WPA2 Enterprise

Authentification : PEAP

Anonymous Id : (none)

Certificate : (none)

PEAP Version : Automatic

Auth. protocol : MSCHAPv2

user name : your_username@uni_domain

password : your_password

I added a 'thawteCA.cer' certificate while trying to get set up at Monash; I'll let you know if it still works at QUT when I try on Monday.

Comment: Yes, our eduroam account works at some, but not all uni's here too. Hopefully they'll get that worked out soon!

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble connecting to eduroam using the above mentioned settings, until i ticked "remember password"